# Read and write to a file in c++

Tags: c++

To write marks and roll n details of students of a class into a file..The output contains only the last entered data.Why is that so?

```
#include<fstream.h>
int main()
{
 ofstream fout;
 fout.open("File1",ios::out);
 char cch;
 fout<<"ROLLNO\t"<<"MARKS"<<"\n";
 int rollno,marks;
 do
 {
  cout<<"Enter the rollno1";
  cin>>rollno;
  cout<<"Enter the marks";
  cin>>marks;
  fout<<rollno<<"\t"<<marks<<"\n";
  cout<<"Do you want to insert more?" ;
  cin>>cch;
 }
while(cch=='y');
 fout.close();

 ifstream fin;
 char ch;
 fin.open("File1",ios::in);
 fin.seekg(0);
 fin.tellg();
 while(fin)
 {
      fin>>rollno;
       fin>>marks;
      cout<<rollno<<"\t"<<marks<<"\n";
  }
fin.close();
return 0;
}
```

Please help me find the error.

Comment: Check that out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Comment: What's your input and observed output?

Comment: Use ios::app instead of ios::out, since the former adds new data to the existing content.

Comment: I have compiled and run on GCC compiler, it's successfully add all number and marks.

Comment: `<fstream.h>` became obsolete at the end of the previous century.  Are you by any chance using an outdated compiler (e.g. Turbo C++_?

Comment: @MSalters it became obsolete in the previous millennium. FTFY

Comment: @all :there seems to be no problem in the way writing happens, only while displaying the output,the most recently inserted data seems to be getting displayed.